# Applying bootstrap accordion functionality on the fly

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

The non-technical staff at our organisation need to be able to create bootstrap accordions but dont have the skills to create them from scratch.  My solution is to allow them to build divs with a class of "accordion-panel" applied and then build the accordion from those divs.

The code I have so far is below but it doesnt apply the actual expand/collapse mechanism.  How do I make it work?

```
<div class="accordion-panel open" id="accordion-panel_open">
   <h4>Why did you do that?</h4><p>fasdfqw fasdf asdf asdf</p>
</div>

<div class="accordion-panel" desc="title of this panel" id="accordion-panel">
   strong text<h4>No really...Why did you do that?</h4><p><br>dfasd fasdf asdf asdf asdf sadf sdf</p>
</div>

<script>

$(document).ready( function() {
  var $code = false;
  var $panels = $(".accordion-panel");

  if ($panels.length > 0) {
    var $panelloc = $panels.last().after('<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">');
    var i=1;
    $panels.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var $heading = $this.find("h4");
      var headingtext = $heading.text();
      $heading.remove();
      var panelcode = '<div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="panel'+i+'"><h4 class="panel-title"><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#info'+i+'" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="info'+i+'">'+headingtext+'</a></h4></div><div id="info'+i+'" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="panel'+i+'"><div class="panel-body">'+$this.text()+'</div></div></div>';
      $("#accordion").append(panelcode);
      i++;
      $this.remove();

    });
  }
});

</script>
```

Comment: where is the div `#accordion`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd have them structure their code a little differently like this:

```
<div id="accordian">
    <div class="panel open">
       <h4 class="title">Why did you do that?</h4>
       <div class="content">
            <p>fasdfqw fasdf asdf asdf</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel">
        <h4 class="title">title of this panel</h4>
        <div class="content">
       strong text<h4>No really...Why did you do that?</h4>
            <p>dfasd fasdf asdf asdf asdf sadf sdf</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is more definitive with what they want to do, and you're not requiring them to put any functional ids in there, other than "accordian".

Here's the script I'd use:

```
$('#accordian')
    .addClass('panel-group');

$('#accordian .panel')
    .addClass('panel-default');

$('#accordian h4.title')
    .removeClass('title')
    .addClass('panel-title')
    .each( function(id){
        $(this).wrapInner('<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#ac' + id + '"></a>');
    })
    .wrap( '<div class="panel-heading"></div>' );

$('#accordian .content')
    .removeClass('content')
    .addClass('panel-collapse collapse')
    .addClass( function(){
        return $(this).parent().hasClass('open') ? 'in':'';
    })
    .each( function(id){
        $(this).attr('id', 'ac' + id);
    })
    .wrapInner('<div class="panel-body"></div>');
```

Here's a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/hshqgvk8/

Comment: Thanks William, I cant get them to alter their code, but using the window.onload event rather than the document.onload did definitely help thanks.

Comment: Excellent.  Glad it helped.  Yep, I've got many of the same type of issues.